# Select from duplicated data into a reduced table with unique lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates, unique

I have created a joined table in SQL Server MS and there are several duplicate lines in it. Now, I need to make a wise selection out of this table, **so that there would be unique line for each *(Item, Recall_Date)* pair based on a specific selection criteria**:

Here is the visual clarification of what I need as pick criteria:

[image: Selection logic from Input table into Output Table]

Basically, my selection criteria should be as below:

> If there are lines as PingPong_FE = 1 & PingPong_Replen = 1, Then pick
>   this,
>
> Else if there are lines as PingPong_FE = 0 & PingPong_Replen = 1,Then
>   pick this,
>
> Else if there are lines as PingPong_FE = 1 & PingPong_Replen = 0,Then
>   pick this,
>
> Else if there are lines as PingPong_FE = 0 & PingPong_Replen = 0,Then
>   pick this
>
> Into the output table.

How should be my SQL query look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge PingPong_Replen and PingPong_FE  columns and get the row which has the max value.

Try this;

```
    select * from 
    (
    SELECT t.item, t.recall_date, t.fe_date , max(t.PingPong_Replen  + t.PingPong_FE)  AS maxPPval
    FROM tableInput  t
    GROUP BY t.item, t.recall_date, fe_date) t1,
    tableInput t2
    where t2.item = t1.item 
and t2.recall_date = t1.recall_date  
and t1.fe_date = t2.fe_date 
and t1.maxPPval = (t2.t.PingPong_Replen  + t2.PingPong_FE)
```

Comment: Great idea Pelin! Thank you!

Comment: Basically, Since PingPong_Replen is more prior than PingPong_FE, I calculate maxPPval as (**2***t2.PingPong_Replen  + t2.PingPong_FE), and it worked very well.

Comment: Good idea! I somehow thought that it is a string field and i want to do string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

May Be like this:

```
 WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT Item, Recall_Date, PingPongFE, PinPongReplen , Row_number() over
 (PARTITION BY Item, Recall_Date ORDER BY Item, Recall_Date) ROW
 FROM Yourtable)
 SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE ROW=1;
```